# Use jq to extract some values from an array to top level, leaving the array intact

Tags: arrays, extract, jq

I have data in this format:

```
{
  "searchResult": [
    {
      "key": "common1",
      "value": "A string"
    },
    {
      "key": "common2",
      "value": "2149944"
    },
    {
      "key": "varying1",
      "value": "604516"
    },
    {
      "key": "varying73",
      "value": "58.92"
    }
  ]
}
```

Within searchResult are some constantly present fields (timestamp, identifiers etc). The other keys are constantly changing and can be named anything. I need them transformed to the format below, with the predefined constant keys pulled out to the top level and the variable keys staying in the searchResult array.

```
{
  "common1": "A string",
  "common2": "2149944",
  "searchResult": [
    {
      "key": "varying1",
      "value": "604516"
    },
    {
      "key": "varying73",
      "value": "58.92"
    }
  ]
}
```

Seeing as jq is already being used in the process, how can I do this transformation in jq please?

I have tried extracting the values using .name, but haven't managed to bring them to this top level.

Many thanks

Ben

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: It was so far off the mark! To the point where I thought .name was a builtin, not just the column name of the example I was copying.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `IN/1` as follows:

```
(.searchResult | (from_entries | {common1, common2})) + { searchResult }
| .searchResult |= map(select(.key | IN("common1", "common2") | not))
```

Comment: Been scratching my head why it would not work on Google Cloud Shell, where I have the necessary network speed to deal with large files. That is running jq 1.5-1 and returned 'jq: error: IN/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:'

Comment: You could add its `def`, which can be found in https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq